# Deleting a fork and pushing to a new repo

Tags: git, github

I was working on a wordpress theming class and forked a repo which I later deleted, because I want to push 100% updated files to a new repo. So the forked one is deleted on Guthub, but I can see that all the commits are still there. When I make a new repository, run init, add -A and commit, I add an additional commit to the same repo, and I am told that the remote doesn't exist anymore.

Is it possible to delete everything on git, or somehow disconnect from the old repo and start fresh?

Here are the errors I had when trying:

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/xampp/htdocs/accelerate/.git/

$ git remote add origin git@github.com:aborisova19/accelerate-marketing.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.


$ git remote show origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: You still have the old deleted origin URL configured - try `git remote -v` to see it. You can remove it with `git remote remove origin`.

Comment: on your local, delete the .git directory. Then `git init` to create a new repository. This will completely clean the history you borrowed from the fork and will let you set a new origin when pushing. Be careful: you are actively taking code from somebody else. Check for licenses and legal aspects.

Comment: git remote -v doesn't show anything, but I can still see all the commits when I git log.

I know that I need to quote my coding bootcamp, there are mentions everywhere in the theme

Comment: So is it possible to fork again and then push my changes? Will the repo be visible with my commits? Doesn't look like I can restore it

Comment: Git is dVCS (Note **d**), so, you are talking about server, client(s), or all of them?

Comment: I'm new at this, so not sure what you mean by server, client(s), or all of them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual description of the remotes is stored in the `.git/config` file : you can look at what is written there under the section `[remote "origin"]`.

The error message indicates that git was not able to make sense of the data stored in the remote (which makes sense if you deleted the repo from github).

---

To remove a remote from your local repo : `git remote rm origin`

After that, you should be able to create a new `origin`.